# Smarty clashing with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am using a .tpl file and have included Jquery tabs to it. Now it gives and error :
Text in bold is the line where it says :

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in header.tpl line 35]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: jQuery('#menu2').tabify(); (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446) in /home/jifcccom/public_html/hrm/_includes/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1093

```
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}_templates/{$THEME}/js/jquery.tabify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[

            **$(document).ready(function () {**
                $('#menu2').tabify();
            });

            // ]]>
        </script>
```

Comment: Which Smarty version are you using?

Comment: Try wrapping your script in a {literal} {/literal} block?

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap JS Code in `{literal}{/literal}`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the js code insdie `{literal}{/literal}`

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu2').tabify();
        });

    {/literal}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to load jquery.js..(i couldn't see it in your posted code)

```
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: this might notbe causing the problem but you jquery.js should be on top of from.js... you might get some error later when using form later if you do so..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a library of jQuery at the top:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/cmxforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{$BASE_URL}_templates/{$THEME}/js/jquery.tabify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  
 {literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu2').tabify();
        });
    </script>
 {/literal}
```

Try enclosing the script tags inside `{literal}{/literal}` tags.

#### [CHECK THIS LINK FOR INFORMATION](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal)

Comment: i missed this : I already have this included : <script src="{$BASE_URL}js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>